# javafx.fxml.LoadException: No controller specified

Tags: java

Im trying to start my application but all i get is this error, im not sure what the problem is im blind haha :P

```
 javafx.fxml.LoadException: No controller specified.
    /Users/galumpen/Downloads/Denkibot/samples/clients/text-client/target/classes/gui/ClientGui.fxml:54

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.getControllerMethodHandle(FXMLLoader.java:557)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:599)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at gui.Main.start(Main.java:28)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have specified `fx:controller="packageName.ControllerClassName"`attribute in the root element/tag in FXML file

Suppose you have `MainController` class in side `controller` package then you have to specify `fx:controller="controller.MainController"`in root element of your FXML file

In the following example see `<AnchorPane prefHeight="474.0" prefWidth="550.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.MainController">`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="474.0" prefWidth="550.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.MainController">
   <children>
      <TabPane fx:id="mainTab" layoutX="106.0" layoutY="116.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="Add Product">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="207.0" prefWidth="314.0" />
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab text="Find Product">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```